# PHP Include file without showing it´s content

Tags: php, smarty

I got 2 files. File B is gtting called in File A. Now i need to edit some things in File B for which i need variables from file A.

I now tried to include File A (parent file) to file B like this:
(I am using SMARTY for my page, basically it´s the sam like a normal PHP include)

```
{include file='file:/standard-usermod.html'}
```

Now when the file gets included i can indeed use the variables of File A but the layout is a mess. It also includes me Layout things of file A, but i only need it´s variables. Is there a posibility with PHP (it does not have to be written in SMARTY) to include a file just for using the variables without showing it´s layout on the page?

Comment: Can you write variables into a file separatly ?

Comment: `ob_start(); include(...); ob_end_clean();`, basically.

Comment: The output buffer manipulation will work but from a software design point of view I guess that you should better decouple these variables and store them in a separate php file. Then include them where they are required without manipulating the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Use ob_clean() after file include